# How do i add 2 references to a single model in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm working on a blogging site(like Medium) which will have a Users model, a Blogs model and a Category model. The basic idea is to store the users in the Users DB, all the blogs in the Blogs DB and the Category DB contains different types of blogs that can be posted.

I wanted to store the reference of the user(who posted the blog) and the category of the blog in the BlogDB. The schemas that i've made are as follows-

**Blog Schema-**

```
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
content: String,
image: String,
createdAt: Date,
blogCategory : {
    id: {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "Category"
    }
},
author: {
    id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    username: String
}});
```

**User Schema-**

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
firstname: String,
lastname: String,
username: String,
password: String,
email: String  });
```

**Category Schema-**

```
var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name : String });
```

Now when i save a blog in the database , it stores all the data correctly, except the 'blogCategory' field. It doesn't even register it. Doesn't even create an empty field with that name.

Is it not possible to add 2 references in a single Schema ? What is it that I can do here ?

Also, i'm very new to NodeJS and MongoDB. Any suggestions here are appreciated. Please advice me on how i can go around implementing this idea or if i should take some different approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Took Me A Little While To Resolve,
First Of All Create Model For Your Schemas:

```
For  user:
var usermodel = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema).
Note: Pass reference for author as 'User' <first argument in mongoose.model()>.

For blogCategory:
var blogCategorymodel = mongoose.model('Category',cateogrySchema).
Note: Pass reference for blogCategory as 'Category' <first argument in mongoose.model()>.

Now we are left with only the saving stuff:

To Save Them Create instances of each user and blogCategory models:
var newuser = new usermodel({give the details}).
var newcateogry = new blogCategorymodel({give the details}).

Now create model for your blog:
var blogmodel = mongoose.model('blog',blogSchema).
Now Create instance of your blogmodel:
var newblog = new blogmodel({give the other details,'author.id':newuser._id,'author.username':newuser.username,'blogCategory.id':newcategory._id})
Now Save All Three:
Promise.all([newuser.save(),newcateogry.save(),newblog.save()]).then((result)=>{console.log(result)})
```